# http errors from preflight calls are not visible in jquery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, preflight

I have built a client application, that uses Ajax to call a WebService on another domain (the server supports CORS).

Sometimes when Ajax makes the preflight call, it gets a http error code 400 or 500 from the server, and a response in the format:

```
{
  "httpStatus": 400,
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

I can see the error in the browsers console, but in my JavaScript code, I just get status 0 and statusText "error". Does anyone know how to retrieve the output from the preflight call in JavaScript?

My Ajax call looks lige this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    data: data || '',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(r) {
        r.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthtoken);
        r.setRequestHeader("X-Client-Version", "0.0.1");
    }
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log("success - service " + url);
    callback(response);
}).fail(function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("fail - service " + url);
    callback(response);
});
```